# shutdown(2) system call does not work for me; I am not sure what am I doing wrong

Tags: c, networking, unix

I am experimenting with shutdown(2) system call.
According to the manual, it does what I want.
When I invoke it in a TCP server in the following way:

```
shutdown(clntSocket, SHUT_RDWR)
```

then clients must be able to observe that TCP connection was closed.
I guess, this means that clients must be able to notice that no further data can be sent/received. This is the theory which I am not able to corroborate.

In this [simple experiment](http://altair.fiit.stuba.sk/tmp) I define a TCP server and a TCP client. The server receives 3 bytes from the client, then invokes shutdown(2). The client sends 3 bytes and subsequently it sends another 3 bytes. Both send operations succeed. Shouldn't the second send operation fail?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on stackoverflow?

Comment: It should include the **smallest** code that shows the problem in the question. Following links is a pain.

Comment: "Shouldn't the second send operation fail?"  How is the socket opened?  How is the write done?  Was it a blocking write?  Or a non-blocking write?

Comment: The socket is opened in the default blocking mode. But maybe I assumed too much. Manuals do not define what will happen if I perform "send" after the other end of the TCP connection performed "shutdown".

On the other hand, I have figured out what to do.
Instead of "send", clients should use "recv". That way they can detect that the other end performed "shutdown" because "recv" returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

A send operation succeeding just means the data was queued for sending. It doesn't mean it was actually sent or received. After calling `shutdown`, you can call `read` if you want to confirm that the other end has completed its part of the shutdown process. Once `read` returns zero or an error, then you know the connection has been shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

When the server calls shutdown(2) with SHUT_WR or SHUT_RDWR, a TCP packet with the FIN flag is sent. FIN means that the sender will not send any more data. It says nothing about the intent to receive data.

The client has no way to know if the server has called SHUT_RD. It doesn't seem to affect the client in any way.